# como podría lograr lo mismo que hace esta función en Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, textarea

Bien... necesito lograr una funcionalidad y encontré una solución pero hace uso de Jquery. Siempre he leído que no se recomienda usar Jquery en Angular 2 y pues he tratado de comprender el funcionamiento de esta función pero aún no lo he logrado. logré subirlo a este [editor online](https://jsfiddle.net/ty9ma541/1/) dónde pueden ver el código y ejecutarlo. En el código es un div, quisiera que fuese un textarea pero trate de modificar el código susituyendo el `div` por un `textarea` y no funciona, no entiendo por que. Pero la idea es que el usuario escriba y que por mas texto que escriba el scroll nunca se active, solo que se reduzca el tamaño de la fuente de dicho textarea, y si el usuario borra texto el texto se vaya agrandando nuevamente. quisiera hacer esto en Angular 8, pero en realidad no tengo mucho tiempo trabajando en el framework y ya tengo horas buscando una solución, es decir, tratando de pasar ese código a typescript sin usar Jquery pero no se me ocurre nada.

Estaba tratande de hacer uso de ViewChild, pero no se me ha ocurrido algo mas.

si alguien me pudiera ayudar un poco estaría enormemente agradecido.

Gracias de antemano!

[EDITADO]

Este es mi archivo index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Familiamag</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
    $.fn.fitInText = function() {
      this.each(function() {

        let textbox = $(this);
        let textboxNode = this;

        let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
          if (observer) {
            observer.disconnect();
          }
          textbox.css('font-size', 0);
          let desiredHeight = textbox.css('height');
          for (i = 12; i < 50; i++) {
            textbox.css('font-size', i);
            if (textbox.css('height') > desiredHeight) {
              textbox.css('font-size', i - 1);
              break;
            }
          }

          var config = {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterData: true
          };
          let newobserver = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
          newobserver.observe(textboxNode, config);

        };

        mutationCallback();

      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner ese código en el `index.html`, después de importar jquery:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
 
$.fn.fitInText = function() {
  this.each(function() {

    let textbox = $(this);
    let textboxNode = this;

    let mutationCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      if (observer) {
        observer.disconnect();
      }
      textbox.css('font-size', 0);
      let desiredHeight = textbox.css('height');
      for (i = 12; i < 50; i++) {
        textbox.css('font-size', i);
        if (textbox.css('height') > desiredHeight) {
          textbox.css('font-size', i - 1);
          break;
        }
      }

      var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true
      };
      let newobserver = new MutationObserver(mutationCallback);
      newobserver.observe(textboxNode, config);

    };

    mutationCallback();

  });
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <my-app>loading</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Y en el componente donde se encuentre el `div` ejecutar la función en el `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
     $('#inner').fitInText();
  }
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcevk9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Actualización**

En el componente donde se llaman las funciones de jquery hay que declarar una constante `$` después de los `import` que sirve para hacer referencia a jquery :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare const $ :any;
```

Comment: Hola amigo! por que en el index? yo estaba tratando de colocarlo en el componente donde queria utilizarlo pero me daba error, decía que la función ```mutationCallback()``` recibía 2 argumentos y se le pasaban 0 argumentos y veo que de la forma en que lo hiciste no muestra ningún error.

Comment: El index es un html normal de toda la vida, donde el jquery funciona de maravilla. En cambio los componentes ya son un mundo diferente porque se mete el ciclo de vida de Angular y typescript y no sé que tanta cosa más. Por eso pensé en ponerlo ahí.

Comment: Entiendo... una última cosita... intenté cambiar el div por un textarea, pero al hacerlo el cambio de tamaño de fuente no tiene efecto. Lo que sucede es que ya venía trabajando con textarea en mi proyecto y para no tener que cambiar eso ya que son muchosss quería cambiar el DIV por un Textarea, pero no funciona.

Comment: Con esa parte te quedo mal, no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: hice todo tal cuál como lo colocaste en StackBlitz pero me muestra este error:  ```core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: $(...).fitInText is not a function at Pag7Component.ngAfterViewInit (pag7.component.ts:52)``` ese es el componente donde estoy haciendo uso de la función, y la función la agregue en el index.html tal cuál.

Comment: Es cierto, lo puse en el código de stackblitz pero no lo mencioné en la respuesta. Ya actualicé.

Comment: Si eso se que es necesario y por ende ya lo tenía en el componente, pero aún así con esa variable declarada me muestra ese error. :(

Comment: Agrega el index a la pregunta para verlo.

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregué.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116448/discussion-between-lobos-and-julianprog).